# React Environment variable inside .json File using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, json, webpack, environment-variables

We have a React application and using webpack configuration in it. We have a situation where we want to use the API_URL and other variables inside .json file based on the environment. We have tried using .env files. But while accessing API_URL inside .json file. It's giving an error unable to access process.

Do we have any option to use API_URL variable inside .json file.?

Webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.html'),
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: 'public' }],
    })
  ],
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8082,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true, // hot-reload
    compress: true, // enable gzip compression
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: false,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common");
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const devConfig = {
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
        filename: 'bundle.dev.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv({
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './.env.development'),
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
};

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, devConfig);
```

.env.development

```
 NODE_ENV=development
 API_URL = "http://localhost:4000"
```

myJsonFile.json

```
  [
  {
    "appId": "xyz",
    "name": "abc",
    "title": "Test",
    "description": "Test",
    "api": "<process.env.API_URL>/myAPI"
}]
```